# Gradiant in playground different from simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cagradientlayer

I tried to make a gradiant using playground then make it into a subclass of uiview to use it in my codebase.

The playground code is like this:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 640, height: 41
    ))

let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer(layer: view.layer)
gradient.frame = view.frame

let lightColor = UIColor(red: 157/256, green: 157/256, blue: 154/256, alpha: 1)
let darkColor = UIColor(red: 108/256, green: 104/256, blue: 104/256, alpha: 1)

gradient.colors = [lightColor.CGColor, darkColor.CGColor]
gradient.locations = [0.6 , 0.4]
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.55)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.45)
view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
view //displayed
```

And display like this:

[image]

I tried to make it into my codebase with:

```
class GradiantView : UIView {
    override var frame: CGRect {
        didSet {
            let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer(layer: layer)
            gradient.frame = bounds

            let lightColor = UIColor(red: 157/256, green: 157/256, blue: 154/256, alpha: 1)
            let darkColor = UIColor(red: 108/256, green: 104/256, blue: 104/256, alpha: 1)

            gradient.colors = [lightColor.CGColor, darkColor.CGColor]
            gradient.locations = [0.6 , 0.4]
            gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.55)
            gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.45)
            layer.insertSublayer(gradient, atIndex: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

However, the result is like this: (no gradiant applied)

[image]

What happened and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

I inverted the locations and it seems to work.
I welcome any explanation on the difference between simulator and playground.

```
      gradientLayer.locations = [0.4 , 0.6]
```